# Using gsub to strip multiple characters

Tags: ruby, gsub

I have an object which contains the following string `"XXXXyyyy!!!!zzzz"`

`XXXX` - never the same, will always change, it may be a million characters long
`yyyy` - will never change, exact number of characters all the time
`!!!!` - this is the data I want to result with after I clean the string. This data will always change as well
`zzzz` - will never change, exact number of characters all the time

so if:

```
string = "XXXXyyyy!!!!zzzz"  
string.gsub("zzzz","")  
# => "XXXXyyyy!!!!"
```

What can I do next to get just `"!!!!"`.  How can I use `'yyyy'`, which is static, to erase `"XXXXyyyy"` and leave only `"!!!!"`.  I hope this explains my question.  Sorry about the last one.

Comment: Please highlight your code by indenting it four spaces, or by selecting it and pressing control+k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it in once:

```
string[/yyyy(.*)zzzz\z/, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

From your first attempt, if you change it to:

```
string = "if(location.hostname.indexOf( 'edition.' ) > -1) {document.write('May 8, 2011 -- updated 1854 GMT (0254 HKT)');} else {document.write('May 8, 2011 2:54 p.m. EDT');}"

string.gsub(/^.+else.+'(.+)'.+$/, $1)
```

Should do it.

Comment: I think they are looking for a regex lookbehind.

Comment: I did this in console and it returned: TypeError: can't convert nil into String from (irb):8:in `gsub'.

Comment: My bad. I was in the rails console. Try this: string.sub(/^.+else.+'(.+)'.*$/, $1)